# What is DataPtr in Qt used for?

Tags: qt

`QVariant::DataPtr` is private, and yesterday I used `QBitArray` to do some work. There's a function `data_ptr()` returning `DataPtr&`, but I don't know when and how to use this function. I write the returning data to a file and opened it in ST2, there shows an `SOH`:

```
int main()
{
    QBitArray bit(8);
    bit[5] = true; //--> I tried bit[7] = true; result is `SOH` still
    QFile file("out");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream outs(&file);
    outs << bit.data_ptr();
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I know `SOH` is the meaning of `Start Of Header`, and it is defined as `0x01`(1byte) for frame delimiting. First I wrote `bit[7]=true;` so I thought `bit.data_ptr()` may be the raw data(00000001 in binary) in `bit` which is an encapsulated `QBitArray`. But when I tried `bit[5]=true;` and opened the file in ST2, it still shew `SOH`. So I'm confused.
[image]

Comment: your question is about QVariant or QBitArray? data_ptr() is nowhere to be seen in the doc, voting for close...

Comment: @UmNyobe I'm asking about `data_ptr()`, I just want to know the meaning of its returned value which is a `QVariant::DataPtr`...

Comment: it is private. Why do you want to know the meaning of a private member? **It was not intended to be used by you**, I dont know why you want to know when to use it.It If you still persist then go to the source code of the class you want, and read how it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataPtr](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h#line396) is just a pointer to [Data](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h#line137) structure. The structure is made private, so you shouldn't use it for anything. However, you can use pointer to it to discriminate two byte arrays. Use [QBitArray::operator<<()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbitarray.html#operator-lt-lt-82) to write bit array into a data stream.

Answer (score 1):

`data_ptr` is a pointer to `Data`. For example, you can use `data_ptr` for converting QbitArray to char*:

```
auto data = bit.data_ptr()->data();
```

so `data[0]` is the size of `bit` (it is 8 here) and others are the value of `bit`. For example:

```
QBitArray bit(16);
bit[5] = true;
bit[14] = true;
auto data = bit.data_ptr()->data();
```

Value of bit is 0x4020. Therefore `data[0]` is 16, `data[1]` is 0x20 and `data[2]` is 0x40.