# What does data_ptr()->data() mean in QBitArray?

Tags: qt

In short here is the code (qt5.9,wingw32 win10 debug32):

```
QBitArray array;
array.resize(32);

//...
//array in hex: 0xaabbccdd

char* data = array.data_ptr()->data();
qDebug() << data[0]; //output: 8

//and the size of data is 5:
//data[0]: 0x08
//data[1]: 0x55
//data[2]: 0xdd
//data[3]: 0x33
//data[4]: 0xbb
```

It seems not like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59909069/12525445) said.
And I did not find the explanation in qt.io documentation.

Comment: The thing is in `QByteArray::resize()` function. It sets the size of the byte array, however, according to the documentation, the new bytes are uninitialized, i.e. can have any value. What you see in your array is not necessarily should be the same data elsewhere else.

Comment: @vahancho It is QBitArray not QbyteArray. If the array is initialized with: QBitArray array(32, 0); the result is the same.